# How to use QtQuickControls2 Style in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml

I had read a article  [The Imagine Style](https://qmlbook.github.io/ch06-controls/controls.html#the-imagine-style)  that can be used in `qml` with `c++` code style.

Which that need `qtquickcontrols2.conf` and [Imagine Style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-imagine.html) or maybe others files.

But I **don't know** how to use it in pyqt style.

I want to know is it posssible to use `The Imagine Style` In pyqt ?

Comment: Do you mean using it for QtWidgets with `setStyleSheet()`? If that's the case, you can't, as Imagine Style, as referred in the documentation, is only for Qt Quick.

Comment: @musicamante It's actually only for Qt Quick Control2, not all of QtQuick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is similar to [PyQt QML Material Design button background won't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48582654/pyqt-qml-material-design-button-background-wont-change/48583334#48583334) one so this post will be generic on how to use the styles of QtQuickControls 2, and my answer is based on translating the options from the official docs: [Styling Qt Quick Controls 2](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html) to python:

#### 1. Using QQuickStyle in Python (Only available for PySide2 and PySide6)

```py
from PySide2.QtQuickControls2 import QQuickStyle
# from PySide6.QtQuickControls2 import QQuickStyle

# ...
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
QQuickStyle.setStyle("Imagine")
```

#### 2. Command line argument

```py
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv + ["-style", "Imagine"])
```

#### 3. Environment variable

```py
os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Imagine"
```

#### 4. Configuration file

**qtquickcontrols2.conf**

```
[Controls]
Style=Imagine
```

**resource.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qtquickcontrols2.conf</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

PyQt5

```
pyrcc5 resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py
```

PySide2:

```
rcc -g python resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py
```

or

```
pyside2-rcc resources.qrc -o resources_rc.py
```

And then you just have to import the module in your main file:

```py
import resources_rc
```

Note: "Imagine" can be changed to any of the styles: Default, Fusion, Material and Universal.

Comment: I use PySide6.1.2 on win10 and follow your step it is work.But it cast out a warnning message `QApplication: invalid style override 'Imagine' passed, ignoring it.Available styles: windowsvista, Windows, Fusion`.

Comment: @jie Why do you use QApplication? In general, QGuiApplication should suffice. On the other hand, that warning is a false positive since it is thinking that you are setting the style to the QtWidgets. skip it or use the other options.

Comment: QApplication can do more things,write `QWidgets` controls  or others fun things.

Comment: @jie If you don't want to see that annoying warning then use the other options, for example:  `os.environ["QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE"] = "Imagine"`

Comment: en,I will try to use your tips.