Setting the Material properties for the root element in QML application does not affect style of the children Items
I want to use a Material theme in my application and I have read the documentation and a lot of examples on how to use that for styling my application. In the official documentation, different forums, and online tutorials, it is stated that If you set the Material theme and other properties like primary or background, it affects all of the children items and unless you want to explicitly override the background color of a button, the button will use the background color specified in the Material.background of the root item.
But in real, when I create a Window and set its material properties, like theme, background, primary and others the buttons in the children items, only use the Material.theme property and other things like background must be set explicitly for theme to work.
I use -style Material argument for running the application with Material theme and also use the QML 5.15 with Pyside2 API for developing the back-end codes.

Have you tried compiling qtquickcontrols2.conf into your pyside resources? See https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols-configuration.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871898/how-to-use-qtquickcontrols2-style-in-pyqt
